# I'm now trying to insert into a table with MySQL, but getting a fatal error message:

Tags: mysql, insert, phpmyadmin

`Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 25833 bytes) in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\libraries\sqlparser.lib.php on line 342`

There are only 241 records of 7 fields, all varchars:

Table:

`create table lawyer_info
(firm_name varchar(100),
firm_url varchar(100),
firm_address varchar(100),
firm_city varchar(100),
firm_state varchar(100),
firm_zip varchar(12),
firm_phone varchar(15));`

Now, if it's the case that the table is too big (which I find hard to believe,) is there a better way of getting it to insert the data?

Answer (score 0):

That's a PHP error.

134217728 Bytes = 134,217,728 Bytes = 134 MB.  With only 241 small records, you must have a logic error in your script that is getting into an infinite loop and continuing to allocate memory.  This is not a MySQL issue.

Check your code.

Comment: Code looks clean to me. It's simply: insert into lawyer_info (firm_name,firm_url,firm_address,firm_city,firm_state,firm_zip,firm_phone)
values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone'),
values('name','url','address','city','state','zip','phone');

Comment: It'd be better to edit your question to include the INSERT query, not put it down here in a comment on an answer.